# Web-based network configuration control panel for Linux hosts

Tags: linux, web-apps, configuration-management, network-administration

I need a solution where I can configure a host network settings from a web frontend.

Ideally, it should be able to analyze and overwrite /etc/network/interfaces.

Yes, I know it can lead to troubles in case of a misconfiguration (just as any set top box), and I can live with it.

Comment: Have you heard of [Webmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webmin)? It's too long ago I've last used it that I could write a recommendation for this, but it should cover your needs (and more).

Comment: @Izzy Wow! It looks quite good. Thank you very much!

Comment: Peter, when you've evaluated it and found it solves your issue, please write an answer (and accept it :)

Comment: @Izzy Yes, so I will do it. And, if I have time, I will check the unanswered questions, maybe I can help others. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Izzy explained, I have tried [webmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webmin) and it works much better as it is common from the control panels.

It has also modules for the network configuration.